# Unexpected Type Error when using Unary Operator --

Tags: java, unary-operator, jshell

I am learning Java and am experimenting with the unary operators --*expr*, *expr*--, and -*expr*.

In class, I was told that --3 should evaluate to 3. I wanted to test this concept in the following assignments:

```
jshell> int t = 10;
t ==> 10
|  created variable t : int

jshell> int g = -3;
g ==> -3
|  created variable g : int

jshell>

jshell> int d = --3;
|  Error:
|  unexpected type
|    required: variable
|    found:    value
|  int d = --3;
|            ^

jshell> int d = --t;
d ==> 9
|  created variable d : int

jshell> int f = d---t;
f ==> 0
|  created variable f : int

jshell> int f = 1---t;
|  Error:
|  unexpected type
|    required: variable
|    found:    value
|  int f = 1---t;
|          ^
|    update overwrote variable f : int
```

My questions:

1. Why does assigning -3 work and not --3? I thought --3 would give 3.
2. Are there cases where --*expr* can be evaluated as double negation instead of decrement?
3. Why can't values suffice where the unexpected type errors were thrown?
4. How did Java evaluate d---t? Also, in what order?

For question 4, the way I thought of it was a right-to-left evaluation. So, if d = 9 and t is 9, the rightmost - operator is the first to act on t, making its value -9. Then the same for the second -, so then t's value becomes 9 again. Then I thought the compiler would notice that d is next to the leftmost operator and subtract the values. This would be 9-9, which evaluates to 0. Jshell shows the expression also evaluated to 0, but I want to make sure my reasoning is correct or can be improved.

Comment: What do you think the answers are? Exactly what parts of explaining them don't you understand?

Comment: Do you mean _decrement_ instead of _deprecation_?

Comment: You can't use the decrement/increment operator (i.e. `--` / `++`) with number literals. They expect a variable because they reassign that variable.

Comment: tgdavies and chrylis-cautiouslyoptimisticI, thank you for your feedback! I edited my post again. Please let me know if more improvements must be made.

Comment: Oh okay. I tried it out more in Jshell and saw it did indeed reassign the variables. Thank you for pointing this out @Slaw.

Answer (score 2):

`--` is taken as the decrement operator. Adding spaces or using brackets will allow it to be interpreted as double negation.

```
int x = - -3;
//or
int x = -(-3);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I still don't know whether my reasoning is correct for my 4th question that was asking how Java is evaluating d---t. It doesn't have spaces so what is happening in that expression?

Answer (score -1):

### Why does assigning -3 work and not --3? I thought --3 would give 3.

1. Java tokenizes the input. A source file consists of a sequence of relevant atomary units, which we shall call words. In `y  +foobar`, we have 3 'words': y, +, and foobar. Tokenizing is the job of splitting them up.
2. This process is somewhat complicated; whitespace (obviously) separates things, but whitespace isn't neccessary, **if** the two 'words' don't share any legal characters. Thus, `5+2` is legal as is `5 + 2`, and `public static` works, but `publicstatic` does not. This tokenization step occurs first and is done on limited knowledge. You could in theory surmize from context that, say, `publicstatic void foo() {}` can't really mean anything else, but the amount of knowledge you need to draw that conclusion is quite complicated, and tokenization just does not have it. Hence, `publicstatic` does not work, but `5+2` does.
3. Based on that rule on tokenization, `int y = --3;` and `int y = - -3` is different for the same reason `publicstatic` and `public static` is different. `--` is a single 'word', meaning: Unary decrement. You can't split it up (you can't put spaces in between the two minus signs), and 2 consecutive minus signs without spaces in between is going to be tokenized as the unary decrement operator, and not as 2 consecutive binary-minus/unary-negative words. You COULD draw the conclusion that `int y = --3;` only has one non-stupid interpretation (2 minus signs), because the other obvious interpretation (unary decrement the expression '3') is a compiler error: You can't decrement a constant. But, that goes back to the earlier rule: If you have to take into account all complications at all times, parsing java source files is incredibly complicated, and for no meaningful gain: You **really** do not want to write source code where things are interpreted correctly or not based on exactly how intelligent the compiler ended up being. It aint english, you want consistency and clarity at all times. Poetic license is not a good thing, when talking directly to computers.

CONCLUSION: `--3`  does not work. It never can. Whomever informed you just messed up, or you misread it, and they were talking about `- -3` and you didn't notice the space, or it got lost in translation.

### Are there cases where --expr can be evaluated as double negation instead of decrement?

Not like that, no. `- -expr` will, `-(-expr)` will, but `--` written just like that, no spaces, no parens, nothing in between? No. Because of the tokenizer.

### Why can't values suffice where the unexpected type errors were thrown?

Because there'd be absolutely no point to this, and makes javac (the part that turns your bag-o-characters into a tree structure and from there, into a class file) a few orders of magnitude more complicated. It's a computer, not english. You don't want 'best effort', and the few languages that do this (javascript, PHP) are incredibly stupid languages, universally derided, for trying (these languages are still popular, but that's despite the property they try their best instead of just having a clear spec and failing when the programmer fails to adhere to it - you'll find plenty of talks for such languages, by fans of it, making fun of the corner cases. In javascript, there's the famous [WAT talk](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat). For java there is the [java puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com) book. Both talks/books designed to teach something by showing off how you can use the language to write idiotic code that is nevertheless hard to read. Written by fans of these languages. It's a bit much to try to give you some sort of proof that you do not *want* a language to take its best wild stab in the dark at what you meant, but hopefully a few popular books and talks will go some way in making you realize it works like this.

### How did Java evaluate d---t? Also, in what order?

Now we're getting into specifics. Java's tokenizer is such that it will tokenize that as `d -- - t` or `d - -- t`, and that's because `---` is not a known word, and the java tokenizer is based on splitting things up by applying a list of known symbols and keywords to the job.

So which one does it tokenize to? It doesn't matter. Why do you want to know? So that you can write it? Don't - what possible purpose does that serve? If you write intentionally obfuscated code, you will be fired, and it'll be justified. If you are trying to train yourself to find that code perfectly readable, that's great! But less than 1% of your average java coder, even expert ones, do this, so now you've written code nobody can read, and you find code others wrote aggravating because nobody writes it like you do. So, you're unemployable as a programmer / you can't employ anybody to help you. You can build an entire career writing software on your own for the rest of your life, but it's *quite* limiting. Why bother?

It gets tokenized into `d - -- t` or `d -- - t`.

If you find this sort of thing entertaining (I certainly do!), then know full well this is no more useful than playing a silly game, there is no academic or career point to it, at all.

The problem is, you don't seem to find it entertaining. If you did, you'd have done a trivial experiment to find out. If it's `d -- - t` (subtract X and Y, where X is d, post-unary-decrement, and Y is t), then after all that, d will be one smaller, which you can trivially test for. If it's `d - --t`, then t would be one smaller afterwards. If it's `d - -(-t)` (as in, d minus Z, where Z is negative Y, where Y is negative `t`), then neither will have changed. You didn't do this experiment. That eliminates 'you find it fun'. I've eliminated 'this is useful', which leaves us with: This question does not matter, therefore neither does the answer.

There is a small chance this question shows up in a curriculum of some sort. If it does, do yourself a giant favour and find another curriculum. It's an incredibly strong indicator of extremely low quality java teaching, if you expect your students to know how `d---t` breaks down.

You talk about 'reasoning', but reasoning has no place here. `d -- - t`, `d - -- t` and `d - -(-t)` are all equally valid interpretations, reason isn't going to tell you which one is correct. The language designers threw some dice to decide. They knew it didn't matter (Except for the last one, which isn't possible without a 'smart' tokenizer, and you don't want one of those, but the reasoning needed to draw the conclusion that you need a smart tokenizer, let alone the reasoning needed to draw the conclusion that smart tokenizers are a bad idea, is incredibly complicated and requires a ton of experience writing parsers from scratch, or possibly a mere full year's worth of parser language courses at a uni level might give you the wherewithal to figure that one out - I think you can be excused for not picking up that detail :P).